# How to limit time value of an input field to current time + 1 hour using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an eCommerce website , where I wish to provide input field/select option for time, where user will select delivery timing , but the issue here is that the select option should be at least 1 hour ahead of current time. Let us say that the current time is 3 pm, then the user should type or select delivery time ahead of  4 pm.

please tell me how can i do that with javascript / jquery .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should take a look at the `moment` js library, it can do exactly that and much more. -> https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

use `getHours() + 1` to set time 1 hour ahead. `getHours()` gets the current time in hours and adding 1 will increment it by 1

```js
var d=new Date();
console.log(d);
console.log(d.getHours() + 1)
```

Comment: Hey , Actually i want user to type time in input field , but restrict hime from typing time within current hour .